# How to manage SQL query with many of joins in a search engine like elastic?

Tags: elasticsearch, sphinx

I have a SQL query which has at least 6 joins. That query takes 10 minutes or above for executing.
Right now I'm using sphinx and I just set a source from that SQL query.
But I have a problem with reindexing.

One of the joins is a join to a dictionary table which updates really often.
I have to reindex the source after every dictionary update.
But I do not want to update the entire index.

For example:

this is SQL query:

> SELECT m.col1, m.col2. m.col3, d.col1 FROM MainTable m JOIN
>   SupportTable t1 JOIN SupportTable t2 JOIN SupportTable t3 JOIN
>   DictionaryTable d

When someone updates *DictionaryTable* I want to update only that part of the index which depends on the updated row.

My target is a real-time interface for my costumes.
The size of the database is very large.

What can I do to make my analytic query faster?
Should I use search engines and make reindex mechanisms or I should use more suitable technologies?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like maybe a SPhinx Real Time index might be suitable. 
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#rt-indexes

You can just send updates for certain documents, rather than having to rebuild the whole index to update a few documents.

But you can only update all fields on a document. Can't just update `d.col1` on lots of documents, will need to provide all the data for all fields (and attributes) for all affected documents.

You can however just update select attributes of documents, without touching the fields and/or other attributes.

---

Another idea is instead of one big index, break down the index into bits - ie 'shard' the index. You can even use a distributed index to make querying all the shards at once easy. (ie to the application it sees just one index, you don't need to manually search separate shards) 
http://sphinxsearch.com/files/tutorials/sphinx_config_tips_and_tricks.pdf

... that way can update the shards on a rolling basis. Ie rather than one '10 minute' query, split into 4 shards and have much smaller updates. 
(ranged queries may even be used to break down into lots of smaller queries, rather than one 2.5minute query) 
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#ranged-queries